# communication between two different components for data exchange/use: Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my view part:

```html
<div>
  <div class="customer">
    <customer></customer>
    </div>
    <div class="addressAndPhases">
      <address></address>     
  </div>
</div>
```

Customer component is getting the **customer data and address data** from the Server.

**CustomerComponent**

```
export class CustomerComponent extends SuperChildComponent {
  public static url: string = 'orderViewCustomer';
  public id;
  public allowed: boolean = false;
  public accessLevel: AccessLevel = null;
  public componentname: string;
  public customerData: Customer = null;

  constructor(private rest: REST, private authenticationService: AuthorizationService) {
    super();
    this.componentname = this.constructor.name;
    this.accessLevel = this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn() ? this.authenticationService.componentAccessLevel(this.constructor.name) : null;
    console.log(this.constructor.name + ' has ' + this.accessLevel);
    if (this.accessLevel == AccessLevel.ENABLED) {
      this.getData();
    }
  }

  private getData(): any {
     this.rest.get(CustomerComponent.url,this.id).subscribe(data=> this.storeData(data.json()), err => console.log(err) ,()=> this.accessLevel==AccessLevel.DISBLED);

  }



  private storeData(res: Object): any {
    this.customerData =<Customer>res;

  }


}
class Customer {
  id: string = null;
  oldId: string = "";
  firstName: string = "";
  lastName: string = "";
  email: string = "";
  addressLine1: string = "";
  addressLine2: string = "";
  addressLine3: string = "";
  street1: string = "";
  street2: string = "";
  postalCode: string = "";
  city: string = "";
  title: string = "";
  gender: string = "";

}
```

Now in address component i want to use some data from component data like this:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="accessLevel">
  <div class="addressAndPhases"  *ngSwitchCase="'ENABLED'">
    <h2 class="label">Address</h2><br>
    <span>{{addressData.addressLine1}}</span><br>
    <span>{{addressData.email}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is how i am trying which is not a right way .

**AddressComponent**

```
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

 public customer:CustomerComponent;
 public addressData;
  constructor() { 
    this.addressData=this.customer.customerData;

  }
```

Problem : I am not sure how can i pass the data from Customer component to address component.

Can i inject customer component into address component's constructor ?

Please give your inputs. Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to provide a service at the parent component and inject it to `CustomerComponent` and `AddressComponent` and use observables to communicate https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the @input and @output decorators ; and the EventEmitter class.
Learn more about it in the [component interaction documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html).

You could also do this with a shared service.